# How to reference external variables inside a sprintf() function in R

Tags: r, odbc, printf, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to write a function to connect to a snowflake database at work. The current function takes the following form -

```
library(DBI)
    library(dplyr)
    library(dbplyr)
    library(odbc)

username <- "myusername@work.com"
    
    hs_snowflake_connection <- dbConnect(
        odbc::odbc(), 
        .connection_string = sprintf(
            "
      Driver={SnowflakeDSIIDriver};
      uid=myusername@work.com; 
      authenticator=externalbrowser; 
      server=work.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com; 
      role=ROLE; 
      warehouse=WAREHOUSE; 
      database=DATABASE; 
      schema=TEAM;
    ", 
    username
        ),
    timeout = 10
    )
```

I am trying to edit this code but instead reference `uid`, `server`, `warehouse`, and `team` from variables saved as R environment variables, but I'm not sure how to reference such variables inside the `sprintf` function. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `%s`

```
sprintf(
            "
      Driver={SnowflakeDSIIDriver};
      uid=%s; 
      authenticator=externalbrowser; 
      server=work.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com; 
      role=ROLE; 
      warehouse=WAREHOUSE; 
      database=DATABASE; 
      schema=TEAM;
    ", 
    username
        )
```